# Proposal for a new filter called 'favourite tags'

Tags: feature-request

Okay, let me show you a screen shot first:-

[image]

I would like to call these 'Filters' available for me to search for questions **without typing anything in the search box manually**. But seriously I would like to take a look at questions that have my 'Favorite' tags. Now you might say that we have this :-

[image]

But then there I can click one tag alone and results are viewed only for that single tag. Now what I feel is we want is a filter called 'Favorite tags'(*which should be available in the bar shown in my first screen shot*). If I click that it should show me what will be shown by this URL(which includes all the favorite tags listed in the second screen shot):-

`http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fglrx+or+ati+or+lightdm+or+radeon+or+conky`

Making it generic :-

`http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/1st_favorite_tag+or+2nd_favorite_tag+or+nth_ favorite_tag`

Wouldn't this make it easy for me to get to the questions I can best answer? Wouldn't it also save me time that I could use to make better answers? 
(You might say 'Just type in the search term!'. But thats fine if a user has just 5 favorite tags as shown above. What about like 10 or 15 tags!)

Think about it. Post your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you were asking for, but: If you follow a tag (by starring it)...

[image]

...you can see an overview of all  recent questions with that tag [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags).

Comment: Though this may not be what I asked, its good to know that such a thing exists! Thanks for the knowledge.